# Create Normal Distributions with Correlation

Tags: excel, statistics

I want to ask a question about how to create two normal distributions with a given correlation but have their own standard deviations and means? I know given two norm distributions x1 and x2 have same standard deviations and means, then the correlation between x1 and px1+p*(1-p^2)^0.5 is p. But I want x1 and x2 have different standard deviations and means.

Comment: can you be more specific? Are you looking for the formula to use? or is it more a general question?

Comment: I am trying to do monte carlo simulation in Excel. I am looking for formula to use.